# PHP XML-RPC - experimental? Should I use the built-in library or the PEAR library?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

It doesn't seem that PHP is short on XML-RPC solutions.

I would prefer to use the one that is actually a PHP extension - https://www.php.net/xmlrpc - since I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, and I will have the library version matching my PHP without too much to worry about (as opposed to the PEAR one, which could possibly be updated beyond my current PHP version).

But there's a warning on all the PHP XML-RPC pages about it being experimental - yet, it's been around for years (implemented in PHP 4.1) and surely should be stable by now? Is this a case of rotten documentation, or should I really avoid this library?

Comment: Lack of documentation alone would make me hesitant.  I've used this library with success: http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/doc-1.1/

Comment: Ive used the [Zend_XmlRpc_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.html) in the recent past when needed.

Comment: @Frank agreed about the lack of documentation - although there is more detail at http://xmlrpc-epi.sourceforge.net/main.php?t=php_api

Comment: Lack of documentation aside - a bit of testing has shown that this library is severely lacking. The 'server' seems not to be able to create a properly formatted <methodResponse>.

Comment: after being frustrated by a bunch of these libraries, we're now using JSON-based API...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen live code that relied on that extension, only PHP libraries like PEAR's XML_RPC or Zend's.